# UI freezing when changing user password in Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am building an android app in MVVM architecture using Firebase. I am trying to do User's password change and whenever i start my code, application freezes or just stops responding. I spent a lot of time to search what is wrong with it and yet no fix. If anyone know why it behave like this I would appreciate your help. My code:

Function called in fragment:

```
private fun startChangePasswordDialog(){
        val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.dialog_change_password, null)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setView(dialogView)
        val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.show()

        val changePassword = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.changePasswordBT)
        val cancel = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.changePasswordCancelBT)
        val passwordET = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.changePasswordET)

        changePassword?.setOnClickListener {
            val newPassword = passwordET.text.trim().toString()

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newPassword) || newPassword.length < viewModel.PASSWORD_MIN_VALUE){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), R.string.password_too_short, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            else{
                viewModel.changeUsersPassword(newPassword)
                viewModel.needUserAuthentication.observe(requireActivity(), {
                    if (it == true) reAuthenticateUser()
                })
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        cancel?.setOnClickListener {
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
```

ViewModel function:

```
fun changeUsersPassword(password: String) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Starting user's password change procedure")
        when (repository.changeUserPassword(password)){
                PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.FACEBOOK_USER -> {
                    _toastMessage.value = R.string.facebook_user_password_change
                    Log.d(TAG, "User's password will not be changed, logged in as Facebook user")
                }
                PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.PASSWORD_CHANGE_ERROR -> {
                    _toastMessage.value = R.string.password_change_error
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error while changing user's password")
                }
                PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.PASSWORD_CHANGED -> {
                    _toastMessage.value = R.string.password_change_success
                    Log.d(TAG, "User's password changed successfully")
                }
                PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.NEED_USER_AUTHENTICATION -> {
                    _needUserAuthentication.value = true
                }
            }
    }
```

Firebase Repository (I have changed it several times when tried to fix this):

```
fun changeUserPassword(password: String): PasswordChangeCallbackEnum {
        var result = PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.PASSWORD_CHANGE_ERROR
        if (currentUser != null) {
            for (userInfo in currentUser.providerData) {
                if (userInfo.providerId == "facebook.com") {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cannot change password for user logged in with facebook")
                    result = PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.FACEBOOK_USER
                }
            }
        }
        try{
            val updateTask = authentication.currentUser?.updatePassword(password)
            updateTask?.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d(TAG, "User's password change state: SUCCESS")
                result = PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.PASSWORD_CHANGED
            }
        }catch (exception: FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException){
            Log.d(TAG, "Need user to authenticate again")
            result = PasswordChangeCallbackEnum.NEED_USER_AUTHENTICATION
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Did you try it on worker thread?
Maybe use coroutines for this and try it

Comment: well... I don't know how is it done but used coroutines and it works. Thank you for your tip :)

Comment: kindly accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are doing task in `ui thread`.

Use `coroutines` for the task to do in `worker thread` .
you can have more information about coroutines. [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html)

You can also use `RxJava` for it  or some `Async` task.

It will prevent the ui freezing